# Link inside of input tag

Tags: html, xhtml

How to display a `a href` and a `img src` inside a input box (text box). ex: i want to display this inside a text box ( `<input id=link` )

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/link" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/img.jpg" border="0" alt="mysite.com"></a>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to put a link inside an input box?

Comment: you can't put it inside, but you can position it absolutely or relatively over it.

Comment: You wouldn't need to put this inside of an input tag to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: well im using zclip jquery script to let users copy the link. for that i need to display it inside input box. kinda like in photobucket.

Comment: What does copying text have to do with a working hyperlink? What's wrong with just putting the URL into the textbox?

Comment: i cannot see any sense in it. Could you explain what is the functionality that you want to do? Why you want to make a link inside a input box? Input box is design to allow you to type text. If you want to make something happen after clicking input box, you can use javascript event "focus". But it makes no sense to perform redirection after focusing an input..
If you want input to look like an image, just just css property background: url(path/input.jpg) and delete default styles like padding:0, border: none; etc.

Comment: i can make it copy the link. i just want to know how to put the link inside text box. when put code image link code inside a text box its giving an error.

Comment: the question is unclear .thanks to @Juhana

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, I would guess that you want an input field that has that HTML code as the default text. You must use character reference codes for quotes and less/greater than signs.

```
<input type="text" value="&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.mysite.com/link&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://www.mysite.com/img.jpg&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;mysite.com&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;" />
```

(By the way, you mentioned "like in Photobucket" -- you can just look at the site's HTML to see how they do it.)

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.

1. Place the image as a background of the input, but this won't be clickable.
2. Absolutely position the element over an input.

1:

```
.myInput { background:url(path/to/img.jpg) 5px 5px no-repeat; }
```

2:

HTML

```
<div class="inputContainer">
    <input class="myInput" type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" />
    <a href="#" class="inputImg"><img src="#" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inputContainer { position:relative; }
.myInput { padding-left:25px; /* This will move the text from under the image */ } 
.inputImg { left:5px; position:absolute; top:5px; z-index:5; }
```

You'll need to play with the position and values depending on your input size, image size and general placement, but that should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As comments mention, you can't literally put a link in an `input` text box (although you could simulate one with JavaScript).

For the background image, use CSS `background-image`.